# SwiftUI: Scroll animation for an Imageview from right to left with a variable

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

Im trying to animate an Image. By now it looks like this:

```
@State private var abstand: var_x = 1
```

and

```
Image("thisIsAnImage")
        .offset(x: CGFloat(-var_x*600+240), y: -300)
```

This script works pretty good since the image will move through the picture.
But I'd like to have a smooth animation. I know I could make the speed slower, but in my context I have to use such a high speed.

I guess there is an option to animate it, but Im fairly new to xcode and most tutorials have more complex animations or initial ones.

Thank you guys for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animations are cued off state changes, either with a [`.animation`](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/animating-views-and-transitions) modifier or a [`withAnimation`](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/animating-views-and-transitions#animate-the-effects-of-state-changes) block.  Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var var_x = 1

  var body: some View {
      Image(systemName: "checkmark")
      .offset(x: CGFloat(-var_x*600+240), y: -300)
      .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1))
      .onAppear { self.var_x *= -1}
  }
}
```

Comment: This works great! Thank you for your help! Im not sure why the *=-1 (that sets a weird location at initializing, but when I set it to *=1 it works great).